# Unable to resolve "expo-av" from "screens/HomeScreen.js"

Tags: react-native, audio, background, config, expo

I have recently upgraded my `expo-cli` to version `2.21.2` and `Expo SDK v33` to get support of Background Playback of Audio. However, I'm getting the error while running the code. consider the code snippet attached below,

```
import { Audio } from 'expo-av';
Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
    staysActiveInBackground : true,
    playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
    interruptionModeIOS: INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DUCK_OTHERS,
    shouldDuckAndroid : true,
});
```

Project Configurations `app.json` just modified `infoPlist` in ios,

```
"infoPlist": {
    "UIBackgroundModes": [
      "audio"
    ]
  }
```

Unable to figure out the issue in setup, or in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to add `expo-av` in your dependencies in `package.json` :

```
npm install expo-av
# OR yarn add expo-av
```

Since SDK 33, expo has released package `expo-codemod` which intends to transform most of theses kind of changes when upgrading an app.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-codemod

For example, after installation, you could execute something like this to automatically fix new imports and upgrade your package.json accordingly :

```
npx expo-codemod sdk33-imports ./src
```

Comment: I'm using Expo SDK 33, According to me in v33 expo-av is preinstalled, doesn't require explicit installation. But still, it worths giving try to expo-codemod

Comment: With sdk33 you have to install extracted packages, either manually , or with codemod